# How to call abstract class method in java

Tags: java, abstract-class

I want to call a method of an abstract class in my own class. The abstract class is:

```
public abstract class Call {

    public Connection getEarliestConnection() {
         Connection earliest = null;

         ...

         return earliest;
    }    
}
```

I want to call the above method, and the calling class is:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Connection c = new Connection();

    private void getCallFailedString(Call cal)
    {
        c = cal.getEarliestConnection();

        if (c == null) {
            System.out.println("** no connection**");
        } else {
            System.out.println("** connection");
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run the above class, it throws a NullPointerException on the line `c = cal.getEarliestConnection()`.  Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Not enough code I'm afraid. We need to see if/how Call is instantiated and where getCallFailedString is invoked.

Comment: how and where you call the getCallFaildString() of MyActivity class?

Comment: Pratik is right: the problem isn't that the class is abstract. The problem is that the value of "cal" is null when you are passing it in.

Comment: thx a lot for ur quick rply. I will edit my above code.

Comment: "Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?" Make sure you are not passing `null` for the `cal` variable, I guess...

Comment: there is no subclass of abstract class Call?? plz post the complete code

Comment: Why do you need such a horrible mechanism? Looking like it makes no sense to use that `abstract` class.

Comment: @Lion yes u right it doesnt make any sense.. may be he's just doing it for some kida prctice.. ;)

Comment: @Lion: I need to use android source code. that's why i am using abstract class

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, `Call` an abstract class, therefore you cannot instantiate it directly. You must create a subclass, say `MyCall extends Call` which overrides any abstract methods in Call.

Getting a `NullPointerException` means that whatever you are passing in as an argument to `getCallFailedString()` hasn't been initialized. So after you create your subclass of Call, you'd have to instantiate it and then pass this in to your method, so something like:

```
class MyCall extends Call 
{ 
     //override any abstract methods here... 
}
```

Wherever you are calling `getCallFailedString()` would then require something above it like:

```
Call cal = new MyCall();
Activity activity = new MyActivity();
activity.getCallFailedString(cal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `Call cal` is null before it is passed into the function `getCallFailedString`.  Make sure you extend `Call` and instantiate the extended class and pass it into `getCallFailedString`.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your object "cal" is initialized and not null. Also, you won't be able to instantiate a Call object(as its an abstarct class). Instead, declare class Call as an interface and implement its method getEarliestConnection(), in your class.

Comment: You can have an instantiated variable of type `Call` by assigning it a value of an instance of any of its child classes.